# fitch proof chapter 13 (ex. 13.29)

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

how to proof exercise 13.29 without using taut con[image]

Comment: Assume ¬∃xCube(x) and ¬Cube(a) and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* proof by *LEM+disjunction elimination* may be rewritten as a proof by *Reduction to Absurdity*.  Take the following structure:

```
 |   P v ~P     TautCon (LEM)
 |  |_ P        Assume
 |  |  :        
 |  |  Q        derived somehow
 |  +
 |  |_ ~P       Assume
 |  |  :
 |  |  Q        derived somehow
 |  Q           Disjunction Elimination
```

When `Q` may be derived from both `P` and `~P`, we may rewrite this to give the required contradiction.

```
 |  |_ ~Q       Assume
 |  |  |_ P     Assume
 |  |  |  :
 |  |  |  Q     derived
 |  |  |  #     Negation Elimination
 |  |  ~P       Negation Introduction
 |  |  :
 |  |  Q        derived
 |  |  #        Negation Elimination
 |  ~~Q         Negation Introduction
 |  Q           Double Negation Elimination
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course first prove Cube(a) v ~Cube(a) using a Proof by contradiction .. the book should have the schema for that

But a little more efficient is to use the following set-up:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! got it

Comment: @user47078 You're welcome!